# Validate if there is a folder and open your PDF file C #

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I want to know the way in which I can validate if there is a folder, validate the folder by the name of the folder like Id, and if it exists, open the files it has inside, in this case they are PDF'S, I explain: I have a path of a server where I have several folders stored

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVKY0.png)

and within those folders I have PDF files, in this case there is only one pdf file inside this folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUuQO.png)

What I want to do is validate if the folder exists (by the name of the folder), and if it exists, open the files that come within that folder

What I want is to know how to show me the file (s) that come inside the folder, as long as the folder exists by name, do the whole procedure at the press of a button and start the validation and open the records.

Comment: Did you try anything? There's a whole System.IO namespace for opening files. Are you truly using Silverlight, a dead technology?

Comment: Have you tried looking into C# documentation? Here is a link to try it out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @mason unfortunately if we use it, but we are migrating to angular, what I see is possible to validate with Directory.exists

Comment: @eddyKroZ Angular is JavaScript and can't run .NET. If you need to find out if directories exist on the client, you can't do that from inside a browser's security sandbox. You can do so from the server side, and then communicate that information back to the client side if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp");
if (!dir.Exists)
    return;
foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
{
    Process.Start(file.FullName);
}
```

You can wrap it in a method and pass the directory and not hard code it, in real life… also, you would potentially open quite a lot of PDF files like this …

when you do:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp");
if (!dir.Exists)
    return;
foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Process.Start(file.FullName);
}
```

You go through all your sub folders as well

Comment: Excellent, i will try that, question, can search the folder by the name of the folder, as if it were the name as the id, example: var dir = new DirectoryInfo (@ "C: \" + nameFolder); ?

Comment: @eddyKroZ just pass a valid directory, all it needs, best to use Path.Combine() when working with directories and files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Great!! i will try this, thank you!!

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2012, but does not recognize the .GetFiles, it is for the version of visual studio?

Comment: Sure it does, it's on the DirectoryInfo class, exists from version 1.1 have a look and this link and change the  framwork version you are using  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=netframework-2.0